# Mocha JS tests - a way to put a callback on sinon spy

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
it('should do something', function(done) {
  var func_spy = sinon.spy(obj, 'method');
  func_spy.on('called', function() {
    // check something
    done();
  });
}
```

Which means that I would like to set a callback on my spy, called when wrapped function gets called (or even better when it returns). Is it possible with sinon or any other library?

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Sinon doesn't provide this (and I don't know about other libraries that do). However, it's generally possible to work around it, although it depends on the exact implementation of the code you're testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call original method using sinon stub and callback. See [here](https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS/pull/278#issuecomment-34047017)

```
   var originalMethod = obj['method']    
   sinon.stub(obj,'method',function() {
       originalMethod();
       //TODO what ever you need     
        });
```

Comment: np, pls accept the answer if you think question is answered.